# Protected oral sex (with condom / dental dam) allowed?

Tags: halal-haram, nikah, practical-islam, sex, husband-wife

With the objections of particularly the sexual fluids such as vaginal secretions, pre-ejaculate and semen entering the mouth and swallowing do any scholars find oral sex of the man with a (flavoured) condom problematic? The condom has flavour so that the wife finds it more enjoyable than tasting latex. The husband I guess would have sensations like for vaginal sex wearing a condom but of course more pleasure would be obtained without a condom for either sex act.

Or do some scholars find the wife sucking the man even with a condom disgusting and not the conduct of a decent human?

The same could be asked of the man sucking his wife with a dental dam or something such as cling film.

Answer (score -1):

Many scholars believe that oral sex is permissible, but the thing you asking about sucking and stuff is disliked in islam. The group of scholars who view oral-genital contact as permissible is mostly as there is no clear verse in Quran or in Hadith prohibiting such act. So yes you probably can have PROTECTED oral sex.

Comment: Salam and welcome to IslamSE the Q&A site about Islam. We require answers here to be well elaborated focused on answering the actual question and any claim to be supported by evidences (see [answer] and check our [help] or take the [tour] for more information).